# FullCalendar on Wordpress integration - wpdb and json issue

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, fullcalendar

I'm looking for help to use fullcalendar in Wordpress.

I'm integrating a schedule from a custom table in phpmyadmin called wp_evenement

So, I've two files

One with template page, where the calendar is displaying and with the script from fullcalendar.
This call an other file called 'events.php' where I'm trying to get json result from database.

I tried to use $wpdb but it doesn't work (or I can't make it work).
And I tried to connect to database with new PDO but it only works when I'm connected as admin...

Does someone help me with global $wpdb solution ?

Here is my code :

**Template :**

```
<div id='calendar' style="margin-top:100px;"></div>    
<script>
            var $ = jQuery;
            $(document).ready(function() {
              var date = new Date();
              var d = date.getDate();
              var m = date.getMonth();
              var y = date.getFullYear();


              var calendar = $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
               editable: true,
               header: {
                left: 'prev,next today',
                center: 'title',
                right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
               },


               events: "https://www.exemple.org/wp-content/mytheme/fullcalendar/events.php/",


               eventRender: function(event, element, view) {
                if (event.allDay === 'true') {
                 event.allDay = true;
                } else {
                 event.allDay = true;
                }
               }

              });

             });

            </script>
```

**events.php**

```
  <?php


// List of events
 $json = array();

 // Query that retrieves events
 $requete = "SELECT * FROM wp_evenement ORDER BY id";

 // connection to the database
 try {
 $bdd = new PDO('mysql:host=***.mysql.db;dbname=****', '***', '***');
 } catch(Exception $e) {
  exit('Unable to connect to database.');
 }
 // Execute the query
 $resultat = $bdd->query($requete) or die(print_r($bdd->errorInfo()));

 // sending the encoded result to success page
 echo json_encode($resultat->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC));

?>
```

**Try with $wpdb**
Works !

```
    <?php

    include_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/wp-config.php';
    include_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/wp-load.php';
    include_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/wp-includes/wp-db.php';


    // List of events
    $json = array();

    // Query that retrieves events
    global $wpdb;
    $requete = "SELECT * FROM wp_evenement ORDER BY id";

    // Execute the query
    $resultat = $wpdb->get_results($requete);

    // sending the encoded result to success page
    echo json_encode($resultat);

?>
```

Comment: you need to include wp-config file in event.php file

Comment: "doesn't work" means what? What error do you get?

Comment: "doesn't work" means that when I'm using wpdb, nothing happened in my calendar or in my events.php file.

Comment: "nothing happens" is not an error message or problem description. Haven't you debugged it (starting from the ajax call and working backwards through the PHP) to find out where things start to go astray?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code.

```
<?php

    include_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/wp-config.php';
    include_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/wp-load.php';
    include_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/wp-includes/wp-db.php';


    // List of events
    $json = array();

    // Query that retrieves events
    global $wpdb;
    $requete = "SELECT * FROM wp_evenement ORDER BY id";

    // Execute the query
    $resultat = $wpdb->get_results($requete);

    // sending the encoded result to success page
    echo json_encode($resultat);

?>
```

your code has spell mistake

try this `$wpdb` insteal of `$wpbd`

Comment: Thanks again Vel, but it doesn't work either... :( The events.php address is still empty and the calendar doesn't receive information.

Comment: Arf, cool I didn' see... Now the events.php et my calendar are still empty BUT I've an 500 Internat Server Error in the console. Big step ! ;)

Comment: One more issue in your query.

Comment: Answer updated. Please check. Don't use pdo in WordPress query.

Comment: Glad to help you. :)